# SCORECARD missing from ChartType ENUM in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Using google sheets, I am working to create a SCORECARD chart type using a script.  I recorded a macro where I visually created the scorecard chart.  All went well.

When attempting to replay the macro, I get an error "Exception: ChartType must not be undefined. (line 167, file "macros").

Here is the offending code from the script:

```
  chart = sheet.newChart()
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.SCORECARD)
```

I reviewed the ENUM definition on the google developer site for [Charts.ChartType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/chart-type) and find that SCORECARD is not shown on the ENUM list of chart types.

Clearly, google sheets is making a macro that it cannot run.  This is a problem.

Any suggestions for how to get around this roadblock? Is there a way to hardcode a specific value for Charts.ChartType.SCORECARD?

Answer (score 1):

There is an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154996585) on Public Issue Tracker for this.

A Googler took a look at it and started investigating. Until that is completed, there is nothing you can do besides waiting for that to be implemented.